# Constraining method or class to accept only optionals

Tags: swift, option-type

I need to constrain API so that users can call it only with types that are explicitly optional. How can I make this happen?

```
class Foo<T> {

    let value: T?

    init(_ value: T?) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let optionalValue: Bool? = true
Foo(optionalValue) // Should work

let nonOptionalValue: Bool = true
Foo(nonOptionalValue) // Should fail, ideally at compile time

Foo(true) // Should work or acceptable to replace it with 
Foo(.some(true))
```

Comment: "I need to constrain API so that users can call it only with types that are explicitly optional" That's a weird requirement and might be an XY problem. Can you share why you want to do this?

Comment: Sure, I'm working on a property wrapper, that is doing some data grabbing from environment, but for testing purposes I want to have ability to override it with predefined values. This values are not always written directly but sometimes (in UI tests) are taken from a registry or other dynamic source. I want consumers of the wrapper to know right away that if the stubs they are providing are non-optional it will always override initial calculations and will be no good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you pass a non-Optional where an Optional is expected, the non-Optional is not rejected; instead, it is implicitly wrapped in an Optional. That is why this line of code is legal:

```
let optionalValue: Bool? = true
```

And for the same reason, this line of code is legal:

```
let nonOptionalValue: Bool = true
Foo(nonOptionalValue) // even though Foo's parameter is typed as Optional
```

You cannot turn off this feature. It is baked into the language. And indeed, as the first example shows, you yourself have come to rely upon it! Thus, for that very reason, you can never prevent a non-Optional from being passed here. That's the price we pay for the convenience of implicit Optional wrapping.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that Optional is not, of itself, a type. It's a generic, so there can be only `Optional<Wrapped>` where `Wrapped` is some specific type.

Comment: Sorry @matt, but that's not helpful

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to declare init with inout property.

```
init(_ value: inout T?) {
    self.value = value
}
```

Now below line gives compiler error "Inout argument could be set to a value with a type other than 'Bool'; use a value declared as type 'Bool?' instead"

```
Foo(&nonOptionalValue) // Should fail, ideally at compile time
```

Constraints:

1. User of class Foo may not want to pass by reference.
2. User will not be able to write Foo(true)

But, these can be worked around by creating a local var before calling the init.

Comment: That's an interesting approach : )